# multi-platform app: ashx or web services?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ashx

I am looking to create a lightweight, heavy traffic, db site. It will be standard 3 tiered architecture in asp.net. Part of this site is web-based, but most of the functions will ideally be available on mobile devices, also.

That being said, I know that web services is the classic answer for this, since I can access a web service from many platforms.  However, I also know that ashx files are the most light-weight. Is there a way to access ashx files from non-web platforms? and if so, how would this compare to a web service to do the same thing.

a good example: a login page that calls either a web service or ashx file to authenticate.

Thanks!

Eric

[EDIT] I was thinking along  the lines of iphone/android/pre type of mobile apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How will you display on the mobile devices?  You've said "web-based" and "mobile devices" but these can be the same thing.  E.g. Through [Control Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx)

You should also look at ASP.Net MVC if you haven't.  It should help with the tiered design and performance that you are looking to get out of your application.

An .ASHX file will efficiently deliver any content type that you require.  That is one of it's key strengths.  So the answer to your question is yes, it can be used to deliver to non-web platforms via SOAP or other HTTP transport schemes.  This would be a lot more involved than using web services.

With your login example, then main benefit that I see is that your ASHX file can use multiple transport schemes, not just SOAP.  So you can use the lighter weight REST for instance.

Comment: Although with .NET 3.5 WCF now supports REST as a first class citizen: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx

Comment: ServiceStack [http://www.servicestack.net/] is a good and light and complete alternative to WCF that can make thins easier.